# How do i extend the time for a gitlab import command?

Tags: gitlab

While using the latest gitlab i tried to import an old repository from an older gitlab server using the handy import function on the newer box. However, after entering all details (which went fine with all other *smaller* repositories) it failed, due to remote hung up.

First: Do i need to configure something on the old server, if so what?
Second: How do i extend the timeout on the newer server, if that is of any help?

It says:

```
Import repository

The repository could not be imported.
Cloning into bare repository '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group-name>/<repo-name>.git'...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I already tried `unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 360` within `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` on the new server.

Comment: How long until you received the hang up?

Comment: first, it was about 30 seconds, but now it seems to be a bit longer. Will stop it, now.

Comment: It now takes ~40 seconds to timeout.

Comment: You increased the timeout on **both** servers? It seems that it's the old server that's timing out, no?

Comment: I think i have to adjust the timeout on the old one, but where/how should i do that? I import using http, since i can't control the ssh keys for an import. Probably the nginx on the other end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, it was a unicorn timeout on the old server. I fixed it with editing `/home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb` setting `timeout=360`.

Do not forget to restart using `service gitlab restart`.

Thanks for your attention. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

With [GitLab 16.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/09/22/gitlab-16-4-released/#expand-configurable-import-limits-available-in-application-settings) (September 2023), that Unicorn timeout is no longer the only setting for GitLab import.

> ### Expand configurable import limits available in application settings
>
> We recently turned a few hardcoded import limits into configurable application settings to allow self-managed GitLab administrators to adjust these limits according to their needs.
>
> In this release, we’ve added the timeout for decompressing archived files as a configurable application setting.
>
> This limit was hardcoded at 210 seconds. On GitLab.com, and for self-managed installations by default, we’ve set this limit to 210 seconds. Both self-managed GitLab and GitLab.com administrators can adjust this limit as needed.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/import_and_export_settings.html#timeout-for-decompressing-archived-files) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/421432).